# Node.js - How to run multiple servers using package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, package.json

Trying to run multiple separate servers in parallel from `package.json`. This method only runs `server1.js`, but ignores `server2.js`

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "demo",
  "main": "server1.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "socket.io": "^1.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server1.js && node server2.js",
  }
}
```

P.S -- code will be used in AWS

Comment: Most people use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently), it handles shutdown more effectively then forking the processes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the shell, `&&` is a command that executes the next command after the previous command is executed, and if the state is true. 
If you want multiple servers to run in parallel at the same time, use the background process commands, `&` or `nohub`.

`node server1.js & node server2.js &`

and now, your application runs in the background, and the process information can be obtained with the command below.
If you want to stop this, get pid information with netstat command
You must delete it with the command kill -9 <your_procees_id>.

```
netstat -vanp --tcp | grep <your_server_port> 
kill -i <your_process_id>
```

Alternatively, there may be a monitoring module such as `pm2`. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2

Comment: As suggested pm2 would be the better answer.